# Dynamic ID - selenium, python. How to match start with and contains?

Tags: python, selenium

I've got `id="phone_123456_option"`. There's no fully static part in code to find the element in other way. I can't also use only start-with, for sure I need also refer to option. So I guess I need to match start-with and contains (or ends-with?) in one line of code using xpath. Does anybody know how to do it properly?

In python and selenium now I can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("phone_123456_option").click()
```

I need to create a python, not xml, xpath:
//*[@id="phone_123456_option"] - How to properly remove dynamic number and refer to phone and option?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'phone') and contains(@id, 'option')]").click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.